# Is there a way to hide Facebook advertisements in an application iframe?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-apps

Does anyone know if it is possible to hide Facebook advertisements in an application iframe?

If not, does anybody have any reference or arguments to explain it to me?

Comment: If the advertisement is a flash based app and the advertisement are integrated inside the flash app, you can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by "an application iframe". Are you the developer or the viewer of this frame? Anyway, this should be down to the viewer. If you are the developer, don't worry about it and don't try to block it because that's most likely against something you agreed upon not do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ad blockers such as Ad-Block Plus https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb

Comment: The OP is probably asking about in-app advertisement :(